# "where are/is your 'ears'?"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Which one of these two sentences is accurate?

> where **are** your "ears"?

> where **is** your "ears"?

Which one is grammatically correct? Why?

Comment: It should be "are," the plural form of the verb, because "ears" is plural.

Comment: I am confused about your level in English since the way you ask the question is more sophisticated than the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ears are plural, meaning multiple of them. If you are just talking about one "ear," you would say:

> Where **is** your ear?

Since you have the -s at the end of ears, you would say:

> Where **are** your ears?

Comment: Note, having an "s" at the end doesn't always make a word plural. "Crisis," "news," "physics," etc. I considered addressing such confusing cases, as well as the potential confusion of collective nouns, but since the OP didn't bring them up, decided to leave it alone.

Comment: @AndyBonner okay, So, Ears are a Plural word.  Right?

Comment: @achen Yes, the singular is “ear,” and the plural is “ears.”